# To what extent does TensorFlow avoid redoing calculations?

Tags: tensorflow

Let us say I have a function called f, that calls two functions: dominant_eig and all_eig. Besides, the function dominat_eig calls the function all_eig. An example is:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


class MyClass:

    def all_eig(A):
        eigvals, eigvecs = tf.self_adjoint_eig(A)
        return eigvals

    def dominant_eig(A):
        eigvals = MyClass.all_eig(A)
        idx = tf.cast(tf.argmax(tf.abs(eigvals)), dtype=np.int32)
        return eigvals[idx]

    def f(A):
        dom_eigval = MyClass.dominant_eig(A)
        eigvals = MyClass.all_eig(A)
        return eigvals, dom_eigval

A = tf.constant([[1,3], [3,1]], dtype=tf.float64)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(MyClass.f(A)))
```

Since dominant_eig uses all_eig, when I call f, the optimal would be that all_eig is only called once, i.e. that the eigenvalues are calculated only once.

1) Given the above code, would the eigenvalues be calculated once or twice?

2) How/where can I check this (I use PyCharm Professional)?

I know I can change the code so that I calculate the eigenvalues once, but I am curious about what TensorFlow does about it (given the above code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues are being computed twice. One simple way to check this is to call the function `all_eig` twice, and see if the returned tensors are the same:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def all_eig(A):
    eigvals, eigvecs = tf.self_adjoint_eig(A)
    return eigvals

A = tf.constant([[1, 3], [3, 1]], dtype=tf.float64)
eigvals1 = all_eig(A)
eigvals2 = all_eig(A)
assert eigvals1 == eigvals2  # AssertionError
```

You can also check the tensor names (i.e. `eigvals1.name`) or use [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) to visualize the graph.